# AttributeError when trying to use send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to send_keys to a webelement but each time I do I get this error

> driver.send_keys("admin")
>
> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://gs.login.com")
cookies = driver.get_cookies()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_id('username')
driver.send_keys("admin")

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

I have look at documentation for selenium and I feel like have added the correct modules, but I still keep getting the same error message.
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_keys()` is an element method, not a webdriver method.

When you call `find_element_by_id()`, you have to save the returned element and then you can call `send_keys()` on that element.

```
username_element = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username_element.send_keys('admin')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the element in a variable first, and then `send_keys` against that

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
element.send_keys("admin")
```